# Testing an IMAP client

Tags: tools, development-process

I am writing an IMAP client library for a Uni project. I need comprehensive, in-depth testing for it. This is the focus even more than the e-mail functionality itself. What should I do? I am looking for a list of tools and actions for the setup and a process/procedures recommendation to prevent introduction of regression when the library will be rev-up'ed, please.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the test suites for any open source IMAP client libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you please be precise if you are developing or looking for test suites in Java.
Also let us know if you are looking at the unit tests?

[Apache Commons mail](http://commons.apache.org/email/download_email.cgi) is one very good open source library to send and receive emails. I am sure they must have come up with loads of unit tests for that library. You can download the source code and try out the unit-tests they have for their IMAP, POP3 etc code and imitate them.

I do not have a readily available links for functional test suites / libraries of any open source tools. but if you are looking for unit tests in java, Apache commons mail should be what you are looking for.